# flutter: Exception thrown while unbinding FCM error

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I installed `firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0` and I done every configuration needed. I send message from firebase console and I received in application.

But I also got this error:

```
I/InputMethodManager(20094): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
W/ConnectionTracker(20094): Exception thrown while unbinding
W/ConnectionTracker(20094): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: ls@5788aac
W/ConnectionTracker(20094):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1870)
W/ConnectionTracker(20094):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1847)
W/ConnectionTracker(20094):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:755)
W/ConnectionTracker(20094):     at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714079@20.47.14 (120306-0):1)
W/ConnectionTracker(20094):     at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714079@20.47.14 (120306-0):2)
W/ConnectionTracker(20094):     at lt.E(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714079@20.47.14 (120306-0):9)
W/ConnectionTracker(20094):     at ld.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714079@20.47.14 (120306-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker(20094):     at ef.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714079@20.47.14 (120306-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker(20094):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
W/ConnectionTracker(20094):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/ConnectionTracker(20094):     at iy.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714079@20.47.14 (120306-0):5)
```

I searched and I found some guild so I added these dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'
```

on app gradle:

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

But I still got error.

This is my Application class:

```
public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }
}
```

Comment: if you're finding `tools:node="replace"` in manifest file, pls remove it and try run again.

Comment: I just have ` tools:replace="android:allowBackup"` @SubairK

Comment: Can we see your dart code? The problem might be with the FCM `onBackgroundMessage` callback.

Comment: This is fcm.configure method https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SgHRTTHqQn/ @Andrej

Comment: You are missing the `onBackgroundMessage` callback. You have to add it to `fcm.configure`. Note: it has to be a top-level function. You can see how to add it here: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging. Scroll down to handling background messages and read requirements 5. and 6.